# How to set default value for a combobox in lightswitch

Tags: c#, combobox, visual-studio-lightswitch

I've created a ComboBox for my search screen and it works as expected.

I'am using code for the binding:

```
partial void SearchStatusTest_Created()
    {
        IContentItemProxy comboControl = this.FindControl("Status");

        comboControl.SetBinding(
        System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty,
        "Screen.ManagerStatusFilter",
        System.Windows.Data.BindingMode.TwoWay);

        comboControl.SetBinding(
        System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty,
        "Screen.Status",
        System.Windows.Data.BindingMode.TwoWay);

        this.Status = this.DataWorkspace.ProjectDeck2Data.Statuses_SingleOrDefault(2);

    }
```

Trying to set the default value the following:

> this.Status = this.DataWorkspace.ProjectDeck2Data.Statuses_SingleOrDefault(2):

Notice that it does work, but still couldn't see the default value in the ComboBox on the screen.

Comment: I would guess that the default value would have to be present in your collection of *displayed* items. Which is not always the same as the collection of values that can be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a riaservice. In this riaservice you can cast your query to a List and add some options.